# Update hotel room reservation array - mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I'm working on a hotel room reservation system. Following are attributes in Room model.

```
rId: String,
        allocation: [{
            date: Number, // 210403 == 2021-04-03
            slots: [{
                type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed,
                ref: 'reservation',
                maxItems: 48
            }]
        }],
        _active: Boolean
```

This "slots" is an array with 48 items(30mins time slots).Here I want to update this array with user inputs.As an example if a user wants to reserve a time between 2.30 - 3.30 i want to update that two slots in array to "reserved".
Following code is the controller for reservation

```
reservation
        .save(reservation) //Save reservation data
        .then((data) => { // Update room slots
            var dt = req.body.checkInDate.substr(0, 10); // extract date from user input
            var tm = req.body.checkInDate.substr(11, 5); // extract time
            dt = dt.replace(/-/g, '');  // 210403 == 2021-04-03
            tm = tm.replace(/:/g, '.');
            console.log(tm)
            console.log(dt)
            Room.findOneAndUpdate({ rId: rId }, { //Update time slot
                $push: {
                    allocation: [{
                        date: dt,
                        slots: [{ tm }]
                    }]
                }
            })
```

Above code is not working. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: no working -- how? do you get an error? what's the desired behavior that you don't see?

Comment: Please add sample data with the expected output and if possible https://mongoplayground.net/

Comment: @ChristianFritz Below i've supplied the out put that i'm getting now.It it not updating upon new reservations

Comment: @TusharGupta-curioustushar  Below i've supplied the out put that i'm getting now.It it not updating upon new reservations

Answer (score 2):

Demo - https://mongoplayground.net/p/bn1lJpZzhUT

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/

```
db.collection.update(
  { rId: 1, "allocation.date": 20190701 },
  { $push: { "allocation.$[a].slots": { a: 1, b: 2 } } },
  { arrayFilters: [ { "a.date": 20190701 } ]}
)
```